# How to point HostGator domain to amazon ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, cross-domain, hosting

I have set the A-Record of the domain to the Elastic IP of the EC2 instance.

I have set the inbound HTTP rule under the security group of my EC2 instance to port 80 and allowed from anywhere.

What else is needed? I waited for 24 hours incase of any propagation issue. But nothing.
HostGator just prompts me to change my nameservers "NS1.HOSTGATOR.COM" and "NS2.HOSTGATOR.COM". But I thought I did not need a hosting package to reroute my domain to an EC2 instance. All I did was "park my domain".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set up everything required to enable domain link. You have to wait no other go. Just wait another couple of hours or contact hostgator customer support.

Given that you have setup the A-Record. I guess you are trying only with the blank domain i.e. `example.com`

Comment: Yeah, I changed the name-servers to a hosting plan I have associated with that account on hostgator.com and it's working now. I thought you didn't need a hosting plan to do it.

Comment: I don't understand why you need a hosting plan; I guess that is your doubt as well. We just a need Domain Service from them. I have many domains in GoDaddy; All that I use is their DNS Zone File Access - the entire APP is from AWS or Azure.